# copy/clone mongoose document from 1 identical schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to copy the content of a document to another one with mongoose?

Ex:

we have 2 schemas, 1 videoSchema and 1 videocloneSchema:

```
var videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    videourl: String
});

var videocloneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    videourl: String
});
```

How would I go about copying the contents of videoclone onto video?
_id is not important, only thing important in the schema is the videourl

Comment: I created an answer to the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041985/4477550