# How to clone a Mongodb database with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to clone a collection or entire Mongodb database (my databases only have one collection so both options are OK) with Mongoose? I saw that there is a possibility to execute raw Mongo commands with Mongoose. What command can I use to clone an entire collection or db from one db to another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is not possible, is there a way to do it with native MongoDB for node instead of Mongoose?

Comment: [db.cloneCollection()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/)?

Comment: Is that possible with Mongoose? I looked at that option but it did not seem to work. @MatinSasan

Comment: In Mongoose Docs I only found out [Schema.prototype.clone()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-clone), which is, I think, not what you want. As for your Mongoose question, here's the answer that I found that (`There is no direct possibility in mongoose.`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/25470961/11330560. I upvoted you and hope someone someday answer this better. That is my question too.

Comment: @MatinSasan Thank you for your comments, indeed, I think it is not possible. The other options are to use Mongodb native driver for Node.js or to make a script which clones/copies the database in shell and automate this script.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time doing this I don't have any reference.

However, this is how I did on my end.

1, I created another collection within the same

```
db: mydb
collections: books, oldbooks
```

2, Since I only know how to connect to one database at a time, I stick to this:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONN_STR);
```

3, On your existing collection, in this case, books, we have this code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var BookSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

4, I created a different Schema for the backup so I can specific the name of the collection:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

    var BackupSchema = new Schema({
      name: String
    }, {
      collection: 'oldbooks'
    })

    module.exports = mongoose.model('BackupBook', BackupBookSchema);
```

NOTICE: that we specified the collection in BackupBook Schema **`collection: 'oldbooks'`**. The idea is to replicate the existing schema to the backup schema.

5, Fetch and save each entry in the collection:

```
 Book.find()
    .exec((err, books) => {
      if(err) throw err
      else {
        books.forEach( (book) => {
          var backup = new BackupBook();

          backup._id = book._id;
          backup.name = book.name;

          backup.save((err, backup) => {
          })
        })
      }
    })
```

TLDR: Create a different collection as backup. Query each entry of the collection then save to the backup Schema individually. Note, the backup schema must specify the name of the collection.